# Conditional configuration and validation of embedded forms in Symfony3

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I'm struggling on the Form and Validation components of Symfony3. I try to set up a rather complex application form (for the sake of simplicity I stripped it down) with an embedded child form (address), collections of child forms (bank accounts) and conditional valdiation.

I do not use Doctrine entities. All form entities are plain old PHP objects.

**1) The form entities**

I use a Application which has a homeAddress property whoch is related to an Address entity and a bankAccounts property which is an array of BankAccount entities.

```
// AppBundle/Form/Application
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

class Application
{
    protected $amount;
    protected $duration;
    protected $email;
    protected $hasBankAccounts;
    protected $bankAccounts;
    protected $homeAddress;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bankAccounts = [];
    }

    ... some getters and setters ...

    public function setHomeAddress(Address $homeAddress = null)
    {
        $this->homeAddress = $homeAddress;
    }

    public function addBankAccount(BankAccount $bankAccount)
    {
        $this->bankAccounts[] = $bankAccount;
    }
}


// AppBundle/Form/Address
namespace AppBundle\Form;

class Address
{
    protected $street;
    protected $houseNumber;
    protected $zip;
    protected $city;

    ... getters and setters ...
}


// AppBundle/Form/BankAccount
namespace AppBundle\Form;

class BankAccount
{
    protected $iban;
    protected $bic;
    protected $bankName;
    protected $holder;

    ... getters and setters ...
}
```

**2) The FormType classes are the following:**

```
// AppBundle/Form/ApplicationType
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ApplicationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Application::class,
            'attr'       => ['novalidate' => 'novalidate'],
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('homeAddress', AddressType::class, [
                'error_bubbling' => false,
            ])
            ->add('bankAccounts', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'        => BankAccountType::class,
                'entry_options'     => ['label' => false],
                'error_bubbling'    => false,
                'allow_add'         => true,
                'allow_delete'      => true,
                'by_reference'      => false,
            ])
            ->add('amount', IntegerType::class, ['label' => 'Kreditsumme'])
            ->add('duration', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $duration])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('hasBankAccounts', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => ['nein' => 'n', 'ja' => 'y'], 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Weiter'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}


// AppBundle/Form/AddressType
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'        => Address::class,
            'attr'              => ['novalidate' => 'novalidate'],
            'error_bubbling'    => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('street', TextType::class)
            ->add('houseNumber', TextType::class)
            ->add('zip', TextType::class)
            ->add('city', TextType::class)
        ;
    }
}


// AppBundle/Form/BankAccountType
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class BankAccountType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'        => BankAccount::class,
            'attr'              => ['novalidate' => 'novalidate'],
            'error_bubbling'    => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('iban', TextType::class)
            ->add('bic', TextType::class, ['disabled' => true])
            ->add('bankName', TextType::class, ['disabled' => true])
            ->add('holder', TextType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

**3) Validation**
I defined validation in the validation.yml:

```
AppBundle\Form\Application:
    constraints:
        - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Application: ~

    properties:
#        homeAddress:
#            - Valid: ~
#        bankAccounts:
#            - Valid: ~
        amount:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "Bitte eine Kreditsumme angeben."
            - Length:
                min: 5000
                max: 50000
                minMessage: "Kreditsumme zu niedrig."
                maxMessage: "Kreditsumme zu hoch."
        email:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail-Adresse an.
            - Email:
                message: Bitte geben Sie eine korrekte E-Mail an.
        hasBankAccounts:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Bitte geben Sie an, ob Sie Bankkonten haben.

AppBundle\Form\Address:
    properties:
        street:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "Bitte eine Straße an."
        houseNumber:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "Bitte eine Hausnummer an."
        zip:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "Bitte eine PLZ an."
        city:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "Bitte einen Ort an."

AppBundle\Form\BankAccount:
    properties:
        iban:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "Bitte eine IBAN an."
        holder:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "Bitte Inhaber angeben."
```

But there are some conditional validations:

- validate homeAddress only if duration is "24" (that doesn't make
  sense but I wanted to implement conditional validation)
- validate bankAccounts if hasBankAccounts is "yes"

Therefore I added a custom ApplicationValidator (as a service) to handle this.

```
// AppBundle/Validator/Constraints
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use AppBundle\Form\Application as ApplicationFormEntity;

class ApplicationValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($object, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($object->getDuration() == 24) {
            $this->context
                ->getValidator()
                ->inContext($this->context)
                ->validate($object->getHomeAddress(), new Assert\Valid());
        }

        if ($object->hasBankAccounts()) {
            $this->context
                ->getValidator()
                ->inContext($this->context)
                ->validate($object->getBankAccounts(), new Assert\Valid())
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works but has some issues. If I do the above conditional validation the errors e.g. of empty address fields are "bound" to the parent form although I set error_bubbling to false.

If I comment it and instead use the Valid constraint in the validation.yml:

```
AppBundle\Form\Application:  
    properties:
        homeAddress:
            - Valid: ~
        bankAccounts:
            - Valid: ~
```

the form errors are correctly bound to the child forms (but they are not conditional anymore).

How can I "bind" the errors correctly? I think I need to use the ExecutionContext in my custom ApplicationValidator but I don't know how.

Besides this I need to know how to get a nested array of errors to use it as json data in my frontend to mark errors when form submitting is done via ajax.

Thanks in advance,
Jens

Answer (score 0):

The template code is the following:

```
{% block content %}
    {#{{ form_start(form) }}#}
    {#{{ form_widget(form) }}#}
    {#{{ form_end(form) }}#}

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.amount) }}
    {{ form_row(form.duration) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    {{ form_row(form.occupation) }}
    {{ form_row(form.homeAddress) }}
    {{ form_row(form.employer) }}
    {{ form_row(form.hasBankAccounts) }}
    {{ form_row(form.bankAccounts) }}
{% endblock %}
```

If I use

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

(as commented out) I get the parent form errors displayed.